# Pentaho-ce 9.3 and Keycloak 18 Integration

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on, keycloak, pentaho

What could be the better approach to integrate pentaho-ce and keycloak. Currently we are working around spring security and a keycloak adapter but we are stuck.

Comment: Please give more context on the problems that you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak adapter is deprecated: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187

See this alternative for OpenID resource servers (REST APIs): https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication